# Is there a way to transfer info from one database into another database?

Tags: mysql

I was wondering today if it was possible to transfer data from one database to another with one query.  Say I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `Table_One` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Type_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Date` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Town` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Desc` longtext NOT NULL,
  `Inserted` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Updated` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `User_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Pending` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=80 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `Table_Two` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Town` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I was thinking of doing something along the lines of

```
INSERT INTO Table_Two (0,SELECT Title, Town, Desc FROM Table_One)
```

This didn't seem right though because how would Table_Two know Table_One was in another database?  Can I use the schema file to make it a more specific query?  Is this even possible to do without using a server side language?

Thanks,
Levi

Comment: Remember to leave out the auto_increment as a named column in the insert as this will fill automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Prefix the table names with their respective databases in your queries, e.g. (if you are running the query from `Table_Two`'s database:

```
INSERT INTO Table_Two (Field1, Field2, Field3) 
SELECT t.Field1, t.Field2, t.Field3 FROM anotherdb.Table_One t;
```

From MySQL documentation

> You can refer to a table within the default database as tbl_name, or as db_name.tbl_name to specify a database explicitly. You can refer to a column as col_name, tbl_name.col_name, or db_name.tbl_name.col_name. You need not specify a tbl_name or db_name.tbl_name prefix for a column reference unless the reference would be ambiguous. See Section 8.2.1, “Identifier Qualifiers”, for examples of ambiguity that require the more explicit column reference forms.

Comment: What does the 't.' reference?

Comment: It references Table_One, it's an alias

Comment: anotherdb.Table_One, it's defined at the end of the statement.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize you could use the alias before actually setting it.  Does that mean that mysql runs through the whole query before executing it?

Comment: Yes, query parsers will validate all syntax prior to execution, in fact many older parsers walked the syntax from bottom-to-top.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can:

```
SELECT ID, TITLE (all the params)
INTO Table_Two
FROM Table_One
```

as long as the tables are identical it should go pretty smoothly.

Hope this helps

Comment: What do you mean by identical? So if one table had a field called "Town_Title" and the other it was "Title" this wouldn't work?

Comment: this won't work as the second database must be mentioned explicitly!

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into schema1.table_two (title,town,desc)
select title,town,desc
from schema2.table_one;
```

Are you talking about different instances?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the source table, this may not be the most efficient way to move data from one database (instance? schema?) to another. I see you have the question tagged, "mysql," so I'm going to assume that's the product you are using. If you're moving a big table from one schema to another (whether they're in separate instances, or not), it may be quicker to use mysqldump to export out of one, and then import into the other.

Comment: I was only curious as to if it is possible to do this and how to do it.  You bring up a good point though of if this is even a good option for a larger table.